# How should I think when combining multiple inequalities?

Tags: inequality, soft-question

When reading/writing papers, I have always find it not obvious when two or more inequalities are combined. For example, taken from my current research

$$\text{Pr}(X \le ab) \le -a (1-p)^{-N} (1 - (1-p)^{-N/2})$$

(here we have $N > 0$, an integer)

Here, I want to find $p$ that will eliminate all the $N$ factors, e.g., $p = 1/N$. But I now will need to plug either one of these inequalities

$$(1 - p) \le e^{-p}$$
$$(1 - p) \ge e^{-p + p^2}$$

I need a rather long time to convince myself to use the second inequality for $(1-p)^{-N}$ and the first for $(1-p)^{-N/2}$.

Is there a technique, shorthand, or something that helps this kind of thinking? Alternatively I would appreciate it if you would share how you approach this kind of problems, so that I may learn how too.

Comment: What you mean by find a $p$ that will eliminate all $N$?  Just choosing a value for $p$ doesn't have any effect on $N$, just $p$.  Perhaps you mean find a bound, e.g., for $(1-p)^{-N}$ which is independent of $N$?

Comment: @Kimball $p$ in my case is the probability of a coin toss, and I can set it to any value I like. I want to find the probability for which, if I set $p$ to this value, the $\text{Pr}(X \le ab)$ can be made to be independent of $N$. I can do this by setting $p = \frac{1}{N}$... I think.

Comment: Right now, it's not entirely clear what you're asking. It would help if you state in the question exactly what $X, N, p, a, b$ are, as well as what specific part of the problem you're referring to with "this kind of thinking".  (How do you come up with $p$, or how to come up with equalities for $1-p$, or how do decide if you want $\le$ or $\ge$?)

Comment: @Kimball I was trying to give an upper bound on the probability. However that's not the point I'm asking -- I was asking what I should do or think when attempting to combine these inequalities, e.g., when trying to give upper/lower bounds. Those are just examples.

Comment: While it may not be the point, it's hard to understand your example without clear definitions.  In any case, now I think I understand what you're asking and will try to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with a slight simplification of your example, let's say you want to find an upper bound for
$$(1-p)^{-N}((1-p)^{-N/2}-1)$$
The general idea is you want to break things down into steps as much as possible. Introducing some algebra will also be helpful.  Here we have a product of 2 positive terms, so it will suffice to get an upper bound for each of these.  (If you want an upper bound for a negative number, it's maybe mentally easiest to think about looking for a lower bound of its negative.)  I rewrote your example on purpose to look like a product of two positive terms, so you don't need to worry about flipping inequalities with multiplication by negative numbers.

First consider $(1-p)^{-N}$, which I think is helpful to write as $\frac 1{(1-p)^N}$.  Now let's introduce some algebra.  You want a bound $X (> 0)$ such that
$$ \frac 1{(1-p)^N} \le X \iff \frac 1X \le (1-p)^N \iff \sqrt[N]{\frac 1X} \le (1-p).$$
Thus you want to use a lower bound for $(1-p)$ here.  The most straightforward thing to do is set $\sqrt[N]{1/X}$ equal to your lower bound and solve for $X$.

Similarly, next you want an upper bound $Y$ for $((1-p)^{-N/2}-1)$.  This means you want $Y$ so that
$$ (1-p)^{-N/2} \le Y + 1.$$
This is similar to the above case, and an upper bound for the product is $XY$.